# Save credit card into Paypal

Tags: php, rest, api, paypal

I am trying to save credit card into paypal using paypal php sdk using the bellow code.

```
<?php
require 'PayPal-PHP-SDK-master/vendor/autoload.php';

$clientId = 'XXXXXXXXXX';
$clientSecret = 'XXXXXXXXX';

use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;
use PayPal\Api\CreditCard;
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;

$sdkConfig = array(
    "mode" => "sandbox"
);

$apiContext =  $apiContext = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential(
    $clientId,
    $clientSecret
));


$creditcard = new CreditCard();

$creditcard->setId(101);
$creditcard->setNumber('4111111111111111');
$creditcard->setType('visa');
$creditcard->setExpireMonth(12);
$creditcard->setExpireYear(2020);
$creditcard->setCvv2(123);

$request = clone $creditcard;
try {
    $output = $creditcard->create($apiContext);
    echo "success";
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex;
    exit(1);

}
```

But it is not working and i got exception like bellow

> exception 'PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException' with message
>   'Got Http response code 400 when accessing
>   https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-cards.' in
>   /var/www/html/test/paypalcard/PayPal-PHP-SDK-master/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConnection.php:202
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/test/paypalcard/PayPal-PHP-SDK-master/lib/PayPal/Transport/PayPalRestCall.php(78):
>   PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection->execute('{"id":101,"numb...') #1
>   /var/www/html/test/paypalcard/PayPal-PHP-SDK-master/lib/PayPal/Common/PayPalResourceModel.php(104):
>   PayPal\Transport\PayPalRestCall->execute(Array, '/v1/vault/credi...',
>   'POST', '{"id":101,"numb...', NULL) #2
>   /var/www/html/test/paypalcard/PayPal-PHP-SDK-master/lib/PayPal/Api/CreditCard.php(443):
>   PayPal\Common\PayPalResourceModel::executeCall('/v1/vault/credi...',
>   'POST', '{"id":101,"numb...', NULL, Object(PayPal\Rest\ApiContext),
>   NULL) #3 /var/www/html/test/paypalcard/cardtest.php(32):
>   PayPal\Api\CreditCard->create(Object(PayPal\Rest\ApiContext)) #4
>   {main}

What is wrong with my code and what changes need to add for this?

Comment: [Update your exception handling](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/exception-%27PayPal%5CException%5CPayPalConnectionException%27-with-message-%27Got-Http-response-code-400-when-accessing) to catch `PayPalConnectionException` and print `$ex->getData()`.

Comment: @camelsWriteInCamelCase , Thanks ,i got the exact error.I am new in paypal SDK.Thanks for this hint